# How to switch between two Intervals in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a digital clock. I made a button and this button changes clock's format(between AM/PM System and 24 hours system). But the problem is when i switch Intervals, both intervals working at the same time and it causes that clocks are changing in seconds.

I tried a lot of thing that i don't remember :/

```
const clock = document.querySelector('.clock');
const changeFormatButton = document.querySelector('.button-formatChange');

changeFormatButton.addEventListener('click', change);

let count = 0;
change();

function showTime24(){

    let date = new Date();
    let hours = date.getHours();
    let minutes = date.getMinutes();
    let seconds = date.getSeconds();

    hours = addZeros(hours);
    minutes = addZeros(minutes);
    seconds = addZeros(seconds);

    clock.innerHTML = `${hours} : ${minutes} : ${seconds}`;

}

function showTime12(){

    let date = new Date();
    let hours = date.getHours();
    let minutes = date.getMinutes();
    let seconds = date.getSeconds();
    let format = changeAMPM(hours);
    hours = changeFormat(hours);

    hours = addZeros(hours);
    minutes = addZeros(minutes);
    seconds = addZeros(seconds);

    clock.innerHTML = `${hours} : ${minutes} : ${seconds} ${format}`;
}

function changeFormat(time){
    if(time > 12){
        time -= 12;
    }
    if(time === 0){
        time = 12;
    }
    return time;
}

function addZeros(time){
    if(time < 10){
        time = '0' + time;
    }
    return time;
}

function changeAMPM(time){
    if(time < 12){
        format = 'AM';
    }
    if(12 < time < 24){
        format = 'PM';
    }
    return format;
}

function change(){
    count++
    let a = setInterval(showTime12, 0);
    let b = setInterval(showTime24, 0);

    if(count % 2 == 0){
        clearInterval(a);
    }
    else if(count % 2 == 0){
        clearInterval(b);
    }
    console.log(count);
}
```

Two clocks are working at the same time. And when i click the button it works more and more.

[image: Gif is here]

Comment: because the old timers are still running. They do not get removed. And since the way it is coded with local variables can't really remove them. And weird you are creating intervals to cancel it.....

Comment: Your conditional in `change` is pretty odd--both of the conditions are the same, so the bottom block in the `else if` will never be executed. Why run two intervals? It'd be a lot cleaner to have one interval running the entire time, and switch what that interval does between multiple behaviors.

Comment: @ggorlen i did that your said, and I succeeded! I am much beginner, i am learning by making mistakes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues here:

1- In your function `change`, when you set new intervals, you are not clearing the previous ones, causing the old and new intervals to overlap.

You should clear the current interval before setting the new ones (perhaps you could have one interval variable then?).

2- Your `if` and `else if` conditions are the same (`count % 2 == 0`), so the `else` block will never execute!

```
var interval = setInterval(showTime12, 0); //a default format

function change(){
    count++;
    clearInterval(interval); //always clear the prev. interval

    if(count % 2 == 0){
        interval = setInterval(showTime12, 0);
    }
    else {
        setInterval(showTime24, 0);
    }
    console.log(count);
}
```

**Edit: A better approach**

As many users pointed out, using a single interval and only changing one little variable, the solution would much be much cleaner. So let's have:

```
var mode = '12'; //say default format is 12

function change(){
    mode = (mode == '12') ? '24' : '12';
}

function run() {
    action = (mode == '12') ? showTime12() : showTime24();
}

var interval = setInterval(run, 0); //a default format
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of extra work in the provided code. It's possible to fix the dead branch

```
if(count % 2 == 0){
    clearInterval(a);
}
else if(count % 2 == 0){ // unreachable!
    clearInterval(b);
}
```

and use this logic to conditionally set an interval (currently, `let a = ...` is locally scoped, so after `change` ends, the previous interval is lost without having been cleared), but an improved design would circumvent the problem entirely.

Instead of using two intervals, a preferred approach would be to continually run one interval and have it perform different kinds of work conditionally.

Additionally, `setInterval(fn, 1000)` can result in some seconds being skipped since the callbacks may be run more than a second apart. Prefer [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), which offers better control for constantly-updating functions.

There is a lot of [repeated logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) in the code. In fact, `showTime12` and `showTime24` are nearly identical. The helper functions can mostly be inlined without compromising readability.

Here's a working example:

```js
const clock = document.querySelector(".clock");
const changeFormatButton = document.querySelector(".change-format");

let militaryTime = false;
changeFormatButton.addEventListener("click", e => {
  militaryTime = !militaryTime;
});

(function showTime() {
  requestAnimationFrame(showTime);
  const date = new Date();
  let amPm = "";
  let hours = date.getHours();
  
  if (!militaryTime) {
    amPm = hours < 12 ? " AM" : " PM";
    hours = hours % 12 || 12;
  }
  
  clock.innerText = `${hours} : ${date.getMinutes()} : ${date.getSeconds()}`
                    .replace(/\d+/g, m => m.padStart(2, "0")) + amPm;
})();
```

```html
<div class="clock"></div>
<button class="change-format">change format</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function change(){
    count++
    function a(){
        let x;
        if(count % 2 === 0){
        x = showTime12();
        }
        else if(count % 2 === 1){
        x = showTime24();
        }
        return x;
    }
    setInterval(a, 0);
}
```

I succeeded thanks to @ggorlen

I just created a function in change function and i set that as setInterval's parameter :)

Good side of being beginner is learning by making mistakes...